# Retrieve selected keys from database from relations

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am using laravel 4 and I have to retrieve registrations and all users associated with that registrations but user table has lot more keys but I only need 3 keys so how can I get selected keys. I know laravel provide select method but its not working on relations.

```
Registration::where('section_id', '=', $key->id)
                                        ->with('user')
                                        ->select('users.id', 'users.name')
                                        ->get();
```

I tried users and user but nothing works. Could someone please post correct way to load this query.

Edit:
- Registration has one user
- Registrations has one section

I have registration table that contains section id and user id. I want to get all users, signed up for particular section. So this is very simple query and its working fine only problem is retrieving selected keys from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Registration` model change your relation to this

`public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('User')->select('id','name');
    }`

And in your controller write this

`Registration::where('section_id', '=', $key->id)->with('user')->get();`

Hope this work for you.